# Confusing by promise object's error chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using promise object in node.js. I have a object:

```
var Send = {
    send(post_ids) {
        return Post.findById(post_ids)
            .then((posts) => {
                return sendArticlesToWechat(setupArticles(posts)); // sendArticlesToWechat is also a promise
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("RESULT: " + result);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("SEND ERROR: " + err);
                return err;
            });
        },
}

export default Send;
```

and call its method in another file:

```
Send.send(req.body)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("CALL SEND: " + result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

When an error occurs, I got two output:

```
SEND ERROR: ERROR: // error message
CALL SEND: ERROR: // error message
```

This error occurred in the `sendArticlesToWechat()` function which be returned. Because it's a promise too so I can `catch` its error outside. This is what I expected.

When I call the `Send.send()`, I expected to get the error in `catch()`, but the error appears in the `then()` method.

According to the output, the error did returned from the previous `catch()`, why I can not keep it in the `catch()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your final `catch()`.  Because you `return err`, you cause the promise to become resolved instead of rejected.  If you want to return a rejected promise, then either remove the `catch()` or re-throw `err`

```
var Send = {
    send(post_ids) {
        return Post.findById(post_ids)
            .then((posts) => {
                return sendArticlesToWechat(setupArticles(posts)); // sendArticlesToWechat is also a promise
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("RESULT: " + result);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("SEND ERROR: " + err);
                //return err;//converts from reject to resolved
                throw err;
            });
        },
}

export default Send;
```

Comment: yes, it works. Thanks. So which one do you think is better? remove the `catch()` or `throw err`?

Comment: That can vary, but in this case I would go with `throw err`. I would do the logging in your `Send` object just in case the calling code forgets to write a `catch()`.  That way at least the logs will show an error happened.